# Getting / Not getting available networks list randomly - Ionic Android Hotspot Plugin

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

This is my code:

```
import {Hotspot, HotspotNetwork, HotspotNetworkConfig} from '@ionic-native/hotspot';

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private hotspot: Hotspot) {
        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            setInterval(() => {
                this.scanNetworks();

                this.scans = [];
                this.scans.push({
                    "networksData": this.networksData,
                });
            }, 1000);
        });
    }

public scanNetworks() {
        this.hotspot.scanWifi().then((networks: Array<HotspotNetwork>) => {
            alert(networks)
            this.networksData = networks;
        }).catch((e) => {
            alert("ERROR: " + e.message);
        });;
    }
```

Sometimes, the output of `alert` is absolutely as I'd expect it to be; i.e. I get a list of all the available SSID, BSSID, and RSSI. But other times (which is most of the times), I don't get absolutely anything in response. It's not falling into the error block because every time `scanWifi` function is a success, but only a handful of times it returns data.

Has anyone experienced this issue before? Please note that I didn't have this issue up until a few days ago.

I am using:

```
"@ionic-native/hotspot": "^4.8.0",
"cordova-plugin-hotspot": "1.2.10",
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by ditching https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/hotspot and using https://github.com/tripflex/WifiWizard2